# AlertDialog with Edittext as custom title view

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need an `EditText` as custom title view in an `AlertDialog`, built by an `AlertDialog.Builder`. Setting and displaying this EditText pans out, as does pasting text to it (via long click on) including EditorActionListener callbacks being called.

But there is no soft input visible, thus adding text to it is quite inconvenient. I already tried calling `InputMethodManager.showSoftInput()`, but nothing happens, neither before and after creating/showing the dialog, nor in `OnClickListener`, nor in `OnFocusChangeListener` nor in a extra `Runnable`.

What makes me stumble is that i have many other AlertDialogs with lots of `EditText`s in them working as desired. Is there a conceptual difference between the custom title view and the content view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

The AlertDialog's AlertController sets flags to block the soft input. Therefore, do this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = .... // initialize, set up
AlertDialog d = builder.show();
d.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
d.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Now soft input shows, resizes the dialog and everything works. (Thanks to GrepCode by the way...).